# how to share data between two scenes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

i would like to know how to move data in from one scene in javafx to another. I know that in server side programming like php you use SESSION, but I have no idea of desktop app

Comment: Try and create a class `Session` that holds the variables you want, and you can either pass it into the new scene or you can just have a `SessionFactory` that you can call statically to retrieve the session.

Comment: The question is very broad and there are many possible answers. Probably the most common way this is done in desktop apps is to use a MVC-type architecture and share a single model instance between the controllers (with a one-one correspondence between controllers and views). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx You can also use dependency-injection frameworks (Spring, Guice, or the JavaFX-specific [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/), or others) to inject the model instance into the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what scope you want to enforce, you can choose one of the following (going from broad to narrow):

A) Use a singleton object that can be accessed globally and allow it to hold any information you require.

B) Use a global/scoped event bus that allows listening for certain events. Attach the scene as a listener to the event bus. The events then carry the information you need to handle the event.

C) Track scenes manually and call methods directly on `Scene` instances for the smallest scope.